# How Configure dns and iis in windows server 2003 for SUBDOMAINS

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, iis, subdomain

i have remote access to my company's server that is using windows server 2003...

some web site (with asp.net) installed on dns and iis...

i am so confused how can i confuge one of this web sites for subdomain - i googled it , but i couldn't understand how figure this out with results...

my dns is like this :

i have three zones in forward lookup :

1-com

mydominname(peter for example)

```
(sameasparent) -> Host(A)

www -> Host(A)
```

2-net

3-org

so every thing is ok for peter.com & www.peter.com

now how can i add a subdomain(sub1.peter.com & www.sub1.peter.com) into peter domain?

Q1. the below answer tell us about iis (but what about www in iis)?

Q2.and what about dns configure for a subdomain (with or without www)?

Q3.AFTER DOING DNS & IIS COFIGURATION WHAT SHOULD I DO FOR GETTING RESULTS (SHALL I STAND FOR 1 DAY FOR GEETING RESULTS OR THERE ARE SOME COMMANDS IN CONSOLE FOR DOING IT FASTER)?

Q4.WHAT COMMANDS CAN I USE FOR CHECK MY SUBDOMAIN IN CONSOLE?

i really would be appreciate for helping me step by step.

thanks a lot
best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying that you want to add a subdomain to IIS? Where do you update the DNS for your domain ? Are you having a child name server ?

```
* Open IIS Management Console.
* Click on the Web Sites folder and select New : Web Site.
* Click on Next to continue.
* Enter the description for your site then click Next. An example would be: sub1.example.com.
* On the IP Address and Port Setting, enter sub1.example.com into the Host header for this Web site field.
* On the next page, enter the path d:\inetpub\wwwroot\example.com\sub1\.
* On the next page, select your options click Next and you're done.
```

Comment: really appreciate -> i updated my Q - plz tell us about www (in both dns and iis) and also about dns configure for a subdomain(with www and without www)...